# Symfony 3 - Doctrine 2: aggregate clause does not work

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, aggregate-functions

I've some issues with symfony + doctrine + Mysql,
So, i'd like to use groupBy for column "numero", it returns the rows grouped by code but it the sum(u.tarif) or count(***) does not work. It display only the first row found as group.

```
public function getDevisGroup($entity) {


    $qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select( 'u.dateCreate', 'sum(u.tarif) as totalPrice, u.number')
            ->from($entity, 'u')
            ->groupBy('u.number');

    return $qb->getQuery();
}
```

To use groupBy, I'have put this option in config.yml:

```
    options:
        1002: 'SET sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode, "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY", ""))'
```

Someone could help me please.
There are the table and the result image
[image: My table Mysql]

[image: Result in my browser]

Answer (score 0):

The issues from the KNP_paginator bundle. 
I changed the kng_paginator in my config.yml to distinct: false and it's work fine.